# i want to display all the points near to given lat and long

Tags: php

```
$ulat = $data['ULat'];
$ulong = $data['ULong'];

$sql = "SELECT PostId, (3959 * acos(cos(radians($ulat)) 
*cos(radians(LocationLat))* cos(radians(LocationLong) - radians($ulong)) + s 
in(radians($ulat))* sin(radians(LocationLat)))) AS distance FROM 
VehicleDetails HAVING distance < 2500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20";


  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('query fails');
  var_dump($query);
```

i get only one row of data,even the distance is 0.When I manually enter the value of LocationLong and LocationLat then it returns correct distance but when varaible is pass as above it returns 0.

my output:array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["PostId"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["distance"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}

Comment: so the `$data` is not initialized correctly, you need to check this variable

Comment: $jsondata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);

datas in $ulat and $ulong are passed correctly, the data from database column LocationLong and LocationLat is not passed correctly, how to solve it